# Bulk API Row Lock Root

Tags: apex, visualforce, bulk-api, locking

How to get confirmation that Inserts/Deletes of Contacts using the Bulk API will cause Row Lock errors on the parent Accounts, especially if the # of Contacts is large and there are few parent Accounts?

And what exactly causes the issue on the parent Account? 
(we have disabled all processes/flows/triggers) turned off for Accounts and issue still occur.

Is there any  some sort of out of the box rollup between Account/Contact that could be the issue.

I have checked the cheatsheet http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/194/0/en-us/sfdc/pdf/record_locking_cheatsheet.pdf 
but unable to get much.

Comment: I am not sure on the root cause of the issue (except the fact that some kind of race condition happening between updates) but usually I set the Bulk Api mode from Parallel to serial in updates and that has solved my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a read of the [Record Locking Cheat Sheet](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/194/0/en-us/sfdc/pdf/record_locking_cheatsheet.pdf).

Inserting or Updating a Contact will lock the **Parent Account**, creating a high risk of lock contention. Especially with a parallel bulk API call.

Can you group your Contacts by parent Account?

You might also want to read [Managing Lookup Skew in Salesforce to Avoid Record Lock Exceptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/04/managing-lookup-skew-to-avoid-record-lock-exceptions.html). Having a large number of Contact child records on an Account results in "[account data skew](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2012/04/avoid-account-data-skew-for-peak-performance.html) which in turn causes performance problems".